# I just want to know that why "message.time" is always returning the value 0

Tags: capl

Before calling below function and have already outputted the `msg1`  which I can see in Trace Window.

```
tmdiff = timenow() - msg1.time;
```

`tmdiff` is always returning the value of `timenow()` and the value of `msg1.time` is always Zero.

Comment: Please help us to help you and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are calling `output(msg1)` and `tmdiff = timenow() - msg1.time` in the same event-handler?

Answer (score 0):

You should also catch your own mesage in the on message routine.
So assumming that msg1 is global to the following.

```
on message *
{
  if ( msg1.id == this.id )
        msg1=this;
}
```